# UITableView delegate methods

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4

I need a `UITableView` delegate method that need to be called from another function at compilation time...is there any default `UITableView` delegate methods that i can use? if not, please comment on how to add an extra delegate method in addition to the existing ones.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do u need to refresh the tableView from another function???

Comment: why do you want to create delegate method? Instead, you can reload all table data after completion of your function

Comment: please provide more information about the problem and what you want to achieve.

Comment: no...actually i used to call an asynchronous datafetch method from didselectRowatindexpath..and it returns only after sometime...meanwhile the code exits from didselectrowatindexpath..i need to apply "[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; only after the asynchronous method gets over..that is from a delegate method

Comment: used a static NSInteger to store the indexpath value before  i exit -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.......and converted it into NSindexpath..and used wherever necessary...as..." [myTableViewName deselectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexpath animated:YES];"

Comment: @AppleDelegate ya,,somewhat so...how?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Make sure you set `UITableview` Delegate in either way - from `NIB` or programatially

**Using NIB**
From Nib  :-

[image]

Programatically :-
[image]

then:-

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
         tblService.delegate=self;
         tblService.dataSource=self;
         [super viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

Use following delegates:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;    //count of section
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [catagorry count];    //count number of row from counting array hear cataGorry is An Array
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
             cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                           reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        // Here we use the provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
        // Ensure you use a placeholder image otherwise cells will be initialized with no image
        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/image.jpg"]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
            cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
        return cell;
    }
```

`Below use for set height of cell`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        return 80;

}
```

`Below use for gatting particular cells data by selecting row this method called`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        Yourstring=[catagorry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];      

       //Pushing next view 
        cntrSecondViewController *cntrinnerService = [[cntrSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"cntrSecondViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:cntrinnerService animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831813/delegate-and-datasource-methods-for-uitableview/42105964#42105964

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this method exist but if you need other methods in a `UITableView` delegate you can Create a new Category of `UITableViewDelegate`.