# adding tableview to static library in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

How to add tableview to static library in `iOS`.

I have already added the `UIKit framework`.

But getting an error as:

```
tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x103bf4
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this your have to write delegate methods http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156927/uitableview-delegate-methods

Comment: Have already added this lines

Comment: tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
as i want to have the tableview in static library, it will not have the didLoad method or viewWillApear method.

Comment: Honestly, I am done helping you, you are not following community guidelines for posting, and you are just spouting stuff out. Please read on how to use the website before just throwing up 3 answers with just code instead of editing the original post

Comment: My only final comment is that this is likely not working because your method is static and you are implementing this as a library, so that library is the delegate, and not your class. So it is looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say static library, but when you put a table into a View Controller you need to make that Controller a UITableViewDelegate and a UITableViewDataDelegate. This is done in the interface or .h file

This will then require a few methods in the implementation file or .m.

One of the methods being number of rows in section.

You can basically just copy the following methods in your implementation and you should be good to go.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return numSections;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return numRows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: just to confirm, when u create static library u get .h and .m files.

Comment: i have written below in .h files

Comment: #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface librarytest1 : NSObject<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

+(UITableView *)makeTableView;

Comment: +(UITableView *)makeTableView
{    
     UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;   
    return tableView;
}

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"newFriendCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"newFriendCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    return cell;
}

Comment: stop posting here in the comments please, no one wants to dig through non-formatted code in a comment chain

Comment: It does not allow me to add code to question as my score is just 7 yet

Comment: I am sorry I don't know how to do it

Comment: Should be able to now, click below your question, there is a button that says edit

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface librarytest1 : NSObject<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

    +(UITableView *)makeTableView;

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end
```

Comment: Do not declare these functions in your interface files. By you declaring a delegate, it lets the compiler know that those specific functions will be in your implementation

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface librarytest1 : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
    +(UITableView *)makeTableView;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "librarytest1.h"

@implementation librarytest1

+(UITableView *)makeTableView {
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.rowHeight = 45;
    tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 22;
    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 22;
    tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    tableView.bounces = YES;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    return tableView;
}
```

Comment: along with this called 2 delegate methods of tableview