# Cannot assign UITableview in xib to custom tableviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, class, uiview, custom-controls

I know this problem has been tackled quite a lot over there but I stil cannot find a solution in this case.

Basically, I have a tableviewcontroller called "TableViewController" that inherits for some reason from another class called "BaseTableViewController" (which inherits from UITableViewController). Everything works fine when I initialize an instance of TableViewController. I have my tableview in full screen.

Because I added a searchbar (which is working) and needed more room for other elements to be displayed, I want to insert this table view inside a UIView. I created an other UIViewController ("MainView") with a xib file and I added a tableview object as a subview.

My problem is I don't know how I can assign this tableview to my custom class I was using before ("TableViewController"). I tired to import the header file (TableViewController.h) in the header file of MainView.h but it does not seem to solve the problem.

Would anyone have an idea how I could link the tableview inside a UIView to a custom tableviewcontroller?

Thanks!

If it can help, below is my mainview with a tableview object I would like to be linked to my custom tableviewcontroller in order to have it with my datasource, delegate, search bar, etc. I cannot insert "tableViewController" in the custom class.

[image]

Comment: As I understand it if you have to put a UItableviewcontroller in the storyboard instead of a UiViewController with a UItableview inside of it. Then you can set the UItableviewcontroller custom class to be your BaseTableViewController.

Comment: The problem is that I need a UIView with a tableview as a subview because I need to add others elements (button, label, etc). I cannot have only a tableviewcontroller. Any idea?

Comment: unfortunately you can't do that, each xib can only have one view controller what you need to do is create a UIViewController and then implement the tableview delegate in the viewcontroller see here for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156927/uitableview-delegate-methods from your BaseTableViewController you need to take the delegate methods and implement them in your new viewcontroller

Comment: if your uitableview is in the uiview then you can only implement a Uiviewcontroller, the controller goes to the base object

Comment: I totally agree but what is the best way to assign the tableview delegate, datasource, etc to my custom tableviewcontroller? Should I initialize an instance of my custom tableview class in the view did load method of my UIViewController and then set the delegate and datasource of my tableview object to this instance? Or should I move all the tableview methods to the UIViewController?

Comment: I think its best to just more all the tableview methods to the UIViewController, that's how I typically do it

Comment: Thanks I will have a try. But how can you do it if you need different classes for a single tableview or if you have already a full well-written tableviewcontroller class that you don't want to copy paste in a UIViewController? There should be a way to just import the class in order to avoid writing a lot of code? And if you need to reuse code? I will try your suggestion. Thx!

Comment: I found the answer. I have to create a storyboard and insert a containerView that is linked to a tableviewcontroller belonging to my custom class