# having name, first and and date show up on tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I am developing an app that can store contacts.  In the table view I have the last name showing up but wish to also have the first name and the right justified the date.  The first name is saved as fist name and the date field as date.  Can any one run me through how to do this?

Thanks

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{


return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
return [secInfo numberOfObjects];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

Contacts *contacts = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = contacts.name;


return cell;
}

-(NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section]name];
}
```

Comment: What's going wrong is I have no clue how to do it.  I tried to add "cell.textLabel.text = contacts.firstname" after the name text field but just got the first name and not both.

Comment: are you using StoryBoards ?

Comment: Yes I am using Storyboard

Comment: I get an "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'NSInteger' error

Comment: This isn't that difficult, use a custom cell with 3 labels.

Comment: Being looking at the custom cell tutorials and still cant figure it out.  I am using core data and most of the tuts I have read are setting the info in the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this . . In the "`cellForRowAtIndexPath`" Method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    UILabel *firstName;
    UILabel *lastName;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        firstName =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,0,250,45)] ;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:firstName]; // As your requirement ,adjust the CGRECT. 

        firstName = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.75 green:0.25 blue:0.25 alpha:1.0];
        firstName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        firstName.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]];

        lastName =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,35,250,30)] ;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lastName];

    }
   firstName.text = ['List' objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    bottomLabel.text=['List_name' objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: When I change to this code, I get three errors " Unknown receiver'_tableView', 'Bad receiver type 'int' at the first List, and then multi-character character constant' at the List_name

Comment: did you synthesise your tableView. ? . " @synthesize tableView=_tableView; "" Or just use "self.tableView" .

Comment: and then about first and last name [Lists of your contacts] should be assign properly according to the tableView delegate.

Comment: "and then about first and last name [Lists of your contacts] should be assign properly according to the tableView delegate.".  Not a clue what you mean here.  Sorry still new at this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831813/delegate-and-datasource-methods-for-uitableview?rq=1 . Go through it , You will get the concept of UITableView.

Comment: @Scubadivingfool You get error for _tableView probably because your tableView is named something else (possibly tableView, without the underscore). The two last sentences in his answer (`firstName.text= ` and `lastName.text=`) should be changed to what you use to get your data. In your code in your question you created a Contact-object, and used contact.name, just do the same for firstName.text and lastName.text.

Answer (score 0):

You want both first name AND last name on the main label, and a date on another? Or all three on the same label? Or in three different as in suggested answer?

This might be the easiest way to achieve something like you're requesting:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)//Setting CellStyle to Subtitle, might have to change that in Storyboard as well, by clicking the cell and choose Subtitle as style
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Contacts *contacts = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //If I understood right, you knew how to get firstName, and lastName(through .name?), but not both at the same time into the same label?
    //Switch out the following 'contacts.firstName' and 'contacts.name' to fit your needs if it's not right:
    NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", contacts.firstName, contacts.name];
    cell.textLabel.text = fullName;
    //And put the date on the 'subtitle'(detailTextLabel). Might not work if the date-variable isn't a text, but another type of object, like NSDate etc.
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = contacts.date;

    return cell;

}
```

If your contacts.date-variable turns out to be an NSDate, take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576265/convert-nsdate-to-nsstring) to put the date in an NSString, and then use `cell.detailTextLabel.text = stringFromDate;`