# Why -tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: is a delegate method instead of a data source method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've found that this method is a UITableView delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return 20;
}
```

I'm really confused, Why it's not a data source method?

Comment: Because,`dataSource` representative of the data model,it should supplies minimal information about view appearance. And `delegate` provides information about appearance. Just like Model and View in MVC pattern

Comment: It doesn't really matter. You need to deal with methods from the data source and delegate. Nothing about any of your code needs to know which of the two protocols the method is from. And sadly, Apple was really inconsistent. Look at the `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocols. Those aren't consistent at all with the `UITableView` protocols.

Comment: I've always wondered the same thing.  From the UITableViewDataSource docs: "As a representative of the data model, the data source supplies minimal information about the table view’s appearance. The table-view object’s delegate—an object adopting the UITableViewDelegate protocol—provides that information."   It seems strange to put layout information in the delegate, the object that feels like it should be responsible for relaying events and actions.  IMO, I don't think there is a real reason.

Comment: I agree with you @IvanLesko ,"It seems strange to put layout information in the delegate..." And when I was going to accept the concepts in the docs, I found there are only two method in UIPickerViewDataSource, the method -pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:  belongs to UIPickerViewDelegate...I got confused once again, perhaps as rmaddy said, "It doesn't really matter"...

Answer (score 1):

This answer gives a good overview of the rough split between `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods: [Difference between UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714528/difference-between-uitableviewdelegate-and-uitableviewdatasource)

In this case, heightForRowAtIndexPath has more to do with the layout of the UITableView than with the content in the individual cells, so it was grouped with the Delegate methods (though the content of the cells and the height can often be very much related)

Comment: thanks, I haven't found that answer before, it helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

`-tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath` method defines the structure of table view cell. It defines the row height. It doesn't set any value in the cell. Methods which provides structural view to table are kept in `UITableViewDelegate` methods.