# Why height related methods are placed in UITableViewDelegate, not in UITableViewDataSource

Tags: ios, uitableview

I found a question in a quiz is "**Which UIKit protocol contains the method –tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:?**"

without taking any load the protocol comes in my mind was **UITableViewDataSource**. But when I checked apple developer documentation, I found I was wrong. **UITableViewDelegate** is the protocol who contain that method.

Before that I understood was that these height methods are part of Datasource protocol.

**Is there any specific reason of placing them in UITableViewDelegate instead of UITableViewDataSource ?**

Why following function are placed in **UITableViewDelegate**

- heightForRowAt indexPath
- heightForHeaderInSection
- heightForFooterInSection

and Why following function are placed in **UITableViewDataSource**

- numberOfSectionsInTableView
- numberOfRowsInSection

Before now I thought these are similar type of function so these methods must be placed in same protocol.

Please make this clear to me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714528/difference-between-uitableviewdelegate-and-uitableviewdatasource)

Answer (score 6):

**UITableViewDelegate** means you provide answers to requests about the layout of the table and about actions the user performs on the tableview.

**UITableViewDatasource** means you provide data for the sections and rows of a table and you act on messages that change a table's data.

For more in details, Check [DataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) and [Delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate)

Answer (score 5):

`numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` are functions that answer questions about the *data to be displayed* which is why they are to be found in the **DataSource protocol**.

The `heightFor...` functions don’t answer anything about the underlying data but only on *the way the data is displayed*. This is why they are part of the **Delegate protocol**.

Does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

The datasource supplies the data, the delegate supplies the behavior.

In [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), datasource is in the model layer and the delegate is in the control layer.

Actually, on second thought, the datasource is usually controller that is lower down, closer to the model. I don't think I've ever used a model object as my datasource.

Answer (score 0):

The `UI` prospects of the `UITableView` are provided by the `UITableViewDelgate` methods and the `data` (we are not talking about the data to be used inside the `cell`, just the information about `UI` (`section`, `row`, etc.) repetitions) needed to construct the `UI` is provided by `UITableViewDataSource` methods.