# Passing data betweeen tableviews(5) using structs and arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, struct

how can i transfer data between multiples table views(5) and in each tableviewcell there is array of data and on clicking the data or element of the array it will send us to next table views cell where data related to the element we click is shown.
i send my data to up to the third table view cell but i have no idea how populate fourth and fifth tableviews cell.
i am using prepare for segue for data passing..

first i want to display my data in the table view and when i click the element of the data it will take me to the next tableview in which related to element we click and so on...

Comment: a better way to do this implement delegate

Comment: can you explain with an example??

Comment: Please for ref follow this https://fluffy.es/handling-button-tap-inside-uitableviewcell-without-using-tag/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous ways of doing this. I usually prefer to assign a model to a TableViewCell and let the cell render itself.

Considering you have a model structure like this:

```
struct MyData: Codable {
    let planets: [Planet]
}

struct Planet: Codable {
    let name: String
    let continents: [Continent]
}

struct Continent: Codable {
    let name: String
    let countries: [Country]
}

struct Country: Codable {
    let name: String
    let states: [State]
}

struct State: Codable {
    let name: String
    let cities: [City]
}

struct City: Codable {
    let name: String
}
```

and a PlanetCell like this:

```
class PlanetCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier = "planetCell"

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    var planet: Planet! {
        didSet {
          renderSelf()
        }
    }

    private func renderSelf() {
      titleLabel.text = planet.name
    }
}
```

In your DataSource for the first TableView you would render a planet:

```
// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PlanetCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! PlanetCell

    cell.planet = planets[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

now when you select a PlanetCell simply use the delegate methods from UITableViewDelegate to perform a segue and pass data to your next ViewController.

```
// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPlanet", sender: planets[indexPath.row])
}

// MARK: - Navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  guard let continentsViewController = segue.destination as? ContinentsViewController else {
    return
  }

  continentsViewController.continents = (sender as! Planet).continents
}
```

just apply the same logic to all your viewcontrollers.

Comment: ergoon can we transfer data from collection view cell to tableview or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `Tag` to `tableView` and With the use of `Tag` you can specify the `tableView` in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt`. 
With `Tag`you can Identify the `tableView` and based on that you can assign value from specific array. Don't forget to add `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDatasource`.

[Difference between UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714528/difference-between-uitableviewdelegate-and-uitableviewdatasource)

You need to just call switch case and return cells.

Comment: sir can you explain with any example , i'm fresher in swift programming